# Expo app published on google play changed to android build and it shows keystore error upon uploading it to google play

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, keystore

[Hello
I have expo app published on google play and it was working fine, it was build with eas build and had expo credentials. Upon noticing that app is not showing the real ads I switched to ./gradlew app:bundleRelease build and tried to upload it to google play but it gives me a keystore error. How do I go about it? Do I generate another key and change it in google console or can i use the same key as before but not sure how exactly. I appreciate any guidance
Thank you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0LxS.png)

I generated another key in android folder but not sure what exactly I have to change in the code and where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request the play console to
[change the key](https://%20https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/key)

you can read about this
[here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Cdescriptions-of-keys-artifacts-and-tools)